# codeception with ms sql? Behat support for mssql?

Tags: sql-server, behat, codeception

Has anyone got this working?

I know the docs say that ms sql support is not tested, so I wonder if anyone had it working?

I have enabled the Db module in acceptance.suite.yml

And my credentials in codeception.yml look like this:

```
modules:
config:
    Db:
        dsn: 'mssql:host=******.db.8876686.hostedresource.com;dbname=*******'
        user: '*******'
        password: '******'
        dump: app/tests/_data/dump.sql
```

In my cest file, I have the following function:

```
    public function testUserDb(WebGuy $I)
{
    $I->seeInDatabase('Users',['Email' => 'someguy@email.com']);
}
```

But I get the following error when running:

```
  [Codeception\Exception\Module]
    (Exception in Db) could not find driver while creating PDO connection
```

So I'm guessing ms sql doesn't work..

It looks like I'm not going to have any joy - anyone know if Behat has ms sql / sql server support?

Thanks

Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behat itself doesn't have anything to do with databases. If you need connecting to one from a Behat context file, you just use whatever is used in your application.

I've successfully used Doctrine with Behat for example, also with mssql.

For mssql integration you will need the [doctrine-pdo-dblib](https://packagist.org/packages/leaseweb/doctrine-pdo-dblib) package.

Comment: Thanks, For what it's worth. I've gone with Behat for the acceptance testing choosing to execute a stored procedure to reset the DB and perform integration tests in isolation.